# Fungus gnats or thrips?

Tags: identification, indoors, pests

I have installed blue traps for indoor plants, and I suspect they catched fungus gnats. However, I've read that fungus gnats are more attracted to yellow traps rather than blue ones. Blue traps are usually meant for thrips.

What type of pest is shown in the picture (taken of one of the caught flies)?

[image: sciariad]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a fungus gnat and the identification is confirmed by the Y shaped vein in the wing.
See [this site](https://hort.extension.wisc.edu/articles/fungus-gnats-on-houseplants/) for details.

We recently used blue sticky strips for thrip control and caught many fungus gnats but no thrip.  The only way we could control the thrip was to remove all the leaves and put the plant outside.

Fungus gnats can be controlled by watering less and, surprisingly, putting cinnamon on the surface of the soil.